# Puppet variable assignment based on facter

Tags: variables, puppet, facter

The following code does not work:

```
case $operatingsystemmajrelease  {
  '6': { $TOUCH = "/bin/touch"}
  '7': { $TOUCH = "/usr/bin/touch"}
}
```

I also tried:

```
case $operatingsystemmajrelease {
"6": { $TOUCH='/bin/touch' }
"7": { $TOUCH='/usr/bin/touch' }
default: { fail('Operatingsystemmajrelease case default triggered.')}
}
```

I am basically trying to assign a value to a variable based on the CentOS major release.

Comment: What is your Puppet version and how is it failing?

Comment: It is the latest puppet version. It is failing because on a CentOS 6 agent I get the message: /usr/bin/touch not found

Comment: You might wish to try unquoted numbers. In Puppet 4, things are not strings by default anymore. The fact that the `'7'` case is invariably hit, however, suggests that Facter might actually report that wrong. Have you checked locally? (E.g. `puppet facts | grep operatingsystemmajrelease`.) Is the agent's `$certname` not unique perhaps?